# I'm trying to develop a (private) hit counter

Tags: php, fwrite

My code attempt uses php functions fopen(), date(), time(), fwrite() and fclose(). There are a few examples I have found (e.g. w3schools)that use several of the components I need  but, in my hands, no joy.

First attempt at code to be included eventually in a bigger page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$logfilename = 'HitRecorder.log';
$logfile=fopen($logfilename,"a");
$remaddr = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SUCURI_CLIENTIP'])) {
    $remaddr = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SUCURI_CLIENTIP'];
$_date=date("d/m/Y");
$_time=date("H:i");
fwrite($logfile,$_date."\t".$_time."\t"$remaddr,"\n");
fclose($logfile);
echo $_date."\t".$_time."\t".$remaddr."<br>";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

This does not access the text file and the echo() produces:    "; ?>

Comment: The `duplicate` is not really a good match for the issue imo - but there are errors in the PHP. There is an unbalanced curly brace and missing concatenation within `..."\t"$remaddr,"\n"`

Comment: @Professor Which should show up as concrete errors once the code starts being executed at all…

Comment: Indeed - these errors should show up if the OP has error reporting on.